# passing pandas dataframe and other objects between two flask routes

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask webapp that I am trying to use to view/retrieve some data from a database (elasticsearch).  For statistical reasons, the data is a simple random sample.  The data from the DB query is returned as a pandas dataframe and is created in one route.  I need to be pass this dataframe into a second route.

Due to randomness, if I try to rerun the DB query in the second route it will naturally return a different random sample.  For reasons out of the scope of this question, elasticsearch does support passing in seeds but these slow down the DB query significantly (and on principle I feel like this shouldn't require 2 separate DB queries).

I have a `view_data` route which lets users look at the data and a second `download_data` route which will either let the user download the file as CSV, TSV or JSON.  I want to let the users view the data, and if the data is what is expected click on a URL to download the dataset they are viewing.

`view_data` looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/view_data', methods=['GET'])
def view_data():
  df = get_random_sample_from_database()
  return render_template('view_data.html', dataframe = df)
```

The html for viewing data `view_data.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- this shows data to user -->
    <pre>
      {% if not dataframe.empty %}
      {{dataframe.__repr__()|safe}}
      {% endif %}
    </pre>

    <!-- when user clicks this URL, it will download data rendered above, not sure how to pass in above dataframe -->
    <a href="{{ url_for('download_data'}}">download above data</a>
  <body>
</html>
```

The function for `download_data`:

```
@app.route('/download_data', methods=['GET'])
def download_data():
  # Use some magic here to get the df created in view_data
  return Response(
    df.to_csv(),
    mimetype="text/csv",
    headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=data.csv"})
```

Here are a few different methods I have investigated:

1. flask sessions: this seems to store data on user's browser as a secure cookie.  I don't want to go this route because the random sample could be anywhere from 1MB to 100+MB.
2. flask.g: I have tried this but can't figure out how to do it correctly as I keep getting `'_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute` type errors.

Here is what I attempted for (2):

```
from flask import g

@app.route('/view_data', methods=['GET'])
def view_data():
  df = get_random_sample_from_database()
  g.data = df
  return render_template('view_data.html', dataframe = df)

@app.route('/download_data', methods=['GET'])
def download_data():
  df = g.data
  return Response(
    df.to_csv(),
    mimetype="text/csv",
    headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=data.csv"})
```

Is there an easy way to generate the dataframe in `view_data` and pass it along to `download_data`?  Is there a better way to let the user view the data with option to download data?

Comment: Do you present the user all data in the `view_date` route? If you are, you might just want to do the processing on the client side and never make a second call to the database. If you aren't, consider giving the data some identifier, and save the table on the server, and remove it after some time.

Comment: `view_date` contains the full data in dataframe, but the entire data isn't rendered in html.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by processing on the client side?  When you say saving the table to the server, is there an easy lightweight way to to do this?

Comment: Processing on the client side would only be relevant if all the data was rendered, but it isn't. What you can do it: 1) user requests data 2) make table, store it serverside, and render fraction of table to user. Give table an id, and put id in form where table is rendered. When user presses download, use this id to retrieve the saved table from the server.

Comment: Storing it server-side means something like [this](https://flask-sessionstore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?  Which appears to store the data in something like redis.  I feel like that would work but might be overkill as it would require setting up redis or some other server/DB

Comment: @divide_by_zero : how did you solved this issue. I am working on similar kind of scenario.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani I never did find an easy way, probably the easiest way is to have an intermediate db call somewhere